# Kendoui Window set X and Y Position

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-window

How do I specifically set a kendo ui window to a location x, y

Ive tried both .x and .left and .y and .right

Neither of these seem to have any effect and I cant find anything online or in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the position property of the window object:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-position

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  position: {
    top: 100, // or "100px"
    left: "20%"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this directly via CSS

```
$("#windowId").closest(".k-window").css({
  top: 200,
  left: 400
});
```